# Is there a Chrome Live Captioning API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, subtitle

Chrome 89 introduced a new live captioning system, that will show up a popup with subtitles created on the fly.

I was wondering if there is any public API for this captioning system, in order to base a chrome extension on it.

I researched and I didn't find anything, but chances are that the API will arrive soon or it's just here but just not documented. Thank you